# Kubernetes Ingress with 302 redirect loop

Tags: kubernetes

I have an ingress with role with two paths:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
metadata:
  name: myservice-production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "30"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ra2.myservice.com.br
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: myservice-production-deployment-nodeport
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /conteudo/
            backend:
              serviceName: seo-production-deployment-nodeport
              servicePort: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - ra2.myservice.com.br
      secretName: ra-production-us2-certmanager-certificate
```

The SEO deployment is correct:

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: seo-production-deployment-nodeport
spec:
selector:
app: seo-production-deployment
ports:
- name: http
port: 80
targetPort: 3003
protocol: TCP
type: NodePort

But when I try to access any route from my conteudo path I'm getting a 302 redirect loop. It's just when using this ingress. If I change, for example, to:

```
- host: ra2.myservice.com.br
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: seo-production-deployment-nodeport
          servicePort: 80
```

It starts working normally. I could not find a reasonable motive to be with this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this annotation :

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Also the change the annotation :

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
```

to this one:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
```

Edit the path - `path: /conteudo/` to - `path: /conteudo`

Comment: Did not work. Same error. 302 redirect loop. I'm taking a look at the application code, to see if it makes any sense, but i think its not.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, any learnings from this? Same issue